# Sending from alternative addresses in Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007, exchange-2003

One of the most frequent requests I get from users with Exchange, is to be able to send from one of their alternative email addresses, that is one of the addreses there account is configured with in Exchange, but that is not their primary address. Unfortuantely as far as I am aware Microsoft have not yet come up with a solution to this.

I've used a number of hacks to get round this, sepearate accounts with POP3 access, Using the from field in outlook, but each have there draw back. What have you used in these situations to allow the use of these alternative addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are only two ways I'm aware of:

One, is to use multiple accounts and have the users change the from field (which makes it basically useless and a maintenance nightmare).

Two, there is a program called [Choose From](http://ivasoft.biz/) that promises to do it, unfortunately it is quite pricey ($239 for 1-2 users).

Comment: Yeah, the from field works, but users don't like it, they want a simple drop down or something of that ilk. Thats why they sometimes prefer the account setup as a pop box that they can choose in the account drop down. I've used choose from, but it is expensive and doesn't always work that great

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help. I'm searching for the magic bullet to this problem also. Maybe one of these days when I get some time I'll just write some software for it...

Comment: Thats ok, I didn't think there would be, just interested in seeing if there were any other ways of getting round the problem. Maybe one day.

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but you could add a POP3 account to the user's profile in Outlook, with the secondary email address. Then misconfigure the incoming mail server and remove the POP3 account from the Send/Receive group.

Now when a new email is created, the "Accounts" button appears on the toolbar to choose which account to send from.

Edit: Re-reading your question, it appears you may already be doing this, but mentioned there are drawbacks...anything specific?

Answer (score 0):

The thing about the "alternate" email addresses on Exchange is that they are not such. They are just aliases to the same mailbox. Aliases main use is to accept incoming emails, but not to be used on outgoing. As far as I know, it is not possible to set identities on Exchange. You can create different profiles on Outlook, for different accounts, but that's pretty much it.

The Choose From program is not an Outlook plugin, it is server centric. By the looks of their webpage, I don't feel too assured as of to try it :-)

Comment: Yeah, we both understand that, unfortunately users done't and are convinced they should be able to do it, the concept of mailboxes is a little alien to most who are used to having this facility when they had multiple pop boxes on there old mail setup. But if we didn't have users where would the challenge be!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is an option in versions of outlook prior to 2007, however in Outlook 2k7, there is an option to send from alternative exchange accounts:

- Select the **Options** tab
- Click **Show From**
- Click **From...** and select the account from which you'd like to send

[image]
This may not be the easiest to manage, but it should get the job done. There may also be ways to restrict who can send from what account, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

OK, the from feild method is not bad been using it.  But it stop working get "you don't have permission to send to thei sreceipitent.  Was this broke by a MS patch or something?